# flutter: how to update the text widget value

Tags: flutter, text, widget

I want to update the value of text widget on click on button.

here is my code

```
Widget text(){
   
    if(workinghours=="0" || gettimeinworkinghours=="0"){   
        
        if(gettimeinworkinghours=="0"){
          totalWorkingHours();
          setState(() {   //here i am using setstate
            return Text(gettimeoutworkinghours,style: TextStyle(
            color: fontcolor,
            fontSize: remainingtextfontsize,
            fontFamily: fontFamily));
          });
         
       
        }
        else if(workinghours=="0"){
        totalWorkingHours();
        return Text(totalTime,style: TextStyle(
            color: fontcolor,
            fontSize: remainingtextfontsize,
            fontFamily: fontFamily)); }
    }
    else{
      return Text(workinghours,style: TextStyle(
            color: fontcolor,
            fontSize: remainingtextfontsize,
            fontFamily: fontFamily)); 

    }
   
       return Text(gettimeoutworkinghours,style: TextStyle(
            color: fontcolor,
            fontSize: remainingtextfontsize,
            fontFamily: fontFamily));

  }
```

i want to update the text widget value to `gettimeoutworkinghours` value, it is working when i press ctrl+s (save), it updates the value but i want to update it automatically, i used setState fo this but that is not working, i call the text() in initState() but it is not working, kindly please help how to do this.

Comment: When you create a new Flutter proejct, it creates a code that doeas exactly what you want. Can you check there how it is done?

Comment: yes, i checked it now, it use setstate(), i update my code where i am using setstate but that doesn't work too! can u please check i am using setstate in  correct way

Comment: thank you! it works, i was calling the setstate( text() ) at wrong place, correct that and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you're in a stateful widget.
2. on button onPressed callback use setState(()=>text())
3. It should update the text widget.

Comment: i call the text() on button pressed setstate it is not working! and using stateful widget too

Comment: thank you! it works, i was calling the setstate( text() ) at wrong place, correct that and it works!

Answer (score 1):

So you are calling the text() in initState(). initState() is only called one time when the widget is loaded for the first time. setState doesn't invoke initState() again

Comment: i remove from initState() but it doesn't work

Comment: u want text() widget code (it is whole which i post), or where i am calculating gettimeoutworkinghours  value?

Comment: thank you! it works, i was calling the setstate( text() ) at wrong place, correct that and it works!